# Why is react router showing a 404 error when serving the React app from index.php on an apache server?

Tags: php, reactjs, apache, react-router, xampp

I built an app and need to deploy it on an existing php site. The problem is, when I load the app, react router breaks and throws a 404 error. I've set up a fresh React app and a local server for testing -- I'm using xampp. When serving index.html from the build directory via index.php, the app loads perfectly fine without react router. Once I add react router, it just shows a 404 page. Does anyone have experience with react router and apache?

index.js

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  { path: "/", element: <App /> },
 
]);
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

index.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
readfile(__DIR__ . '/build/index.html');
?>
```

In package.json:

```
 "homepage": "/test-app/build/"
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

As I said, if I replace router provider with app, it works fine, so it's specifically a react router issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to add a basename to createBrowserRouter.

```
createBrowserRouter(routes, { basename: "/test-app" })
```